# Visual Studio - How to create and use a template?

Tags: c++, templates, import, export, sfml

I have got the SFML library, for graphics etc for C++. Is there a way to save a template with its settings, and then create a new project with that template? This would much easier, instead of linking up the library and all the files every time. I have tried creating a template, but when I open it, there is no code. Thanks

Comment: No luck [here](https://www.google.de/search?ei=s1w2Wqy4Ocv7kwXL-Yj4Bw&q=visual+studio+create+project+template&oq=visual+studio+create+pro&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0l10.4019990.4031785.0.4035145.24.19.0.5.5.0.181.1820.17j2.19.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.24.1863...35i39k1j0i67k1.0.Fx3EqDvEDRo)?

Comment: @user0042 I don't think I was searching the right thing. Thank you so much

Comment: @user0042 oh wait no - I tried that and it still didn't fix the problem. When I look in the folder after making a project with the template, all the SFML have gone, and some other files